# Why is apache dtd for struts throwing errors

Tags: apache, struts, dtd

This morning several branches of a system I am working on all started to break with the following error messages:
(everything was fine last night)

```
 [37m2018-09-12 11:55:34.733[0;39m [1;31mERROR[0;39m [37m--- [           main]
 [0;39m [     ] 36mcom.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper  
 [0;39m : The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed. at (-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN:1:3)
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
```

The reference is in struts.xml which looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
 "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts 
  Configuration 2.5//EN"
 "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
```

Going to the above url i get this message:

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 35 at column 2: StartTag: invalid 
element name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first 
error.
```

Since this just started happening across several branches, some of which have not had any changes to their struts.xml file, I am guessing this is an apache problem. Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: posting on apache struts site:   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4959?filter=-6

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error just today.

Try using http-secure URL; "https://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd" as DTD.

But I don't clearly understand the true reason.

Comment: tried that, same error. Using that url in browser display an error as well.

Answer (score 0):

apache just posted that they fixed the issue

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4959